# cakephp : Table for model was not found in datasource default

Tags: cakephp

I don't understand, i put manually my table in my cakephp model :

```
<?php 
class Configs extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'data_configs';
}
```

I have the error `Table data_configs for model Configs was not found in datasource default`.

If i change my table for a other table in my mysql, it's working... what is the problem ? My table exists and not empty.

Comment: What is your table name in mysql database?

Comment: Make sure the credentials used by your datasource _default_ has access to that table.

Answer (score 6):

Try clear Cake's cache:

```
$ cd app/tmp/cache
$ find . -type f -delete
```